# Sender name on SMS

Tags: react-native, sms

I'm using the react-native-get-sms-android library to send verification sms through my operator number

I'm using the react-native-get-sms-android library to send verification sms through my operator number, I would like to know if it is possible for me as the sender to choose a name to be displayed to the recipient instead of my number? Example: My Business instead of +1 351 589 5458

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The sender name is usually determined by the carrier or the recipient’s device, and it depends on whether the number is registered in their contacts or not. You can try to register your business name with your carrier.